# Dell Inspiron Bluetooth not working

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, dell-inspiron

So i just recently setup my Dell Inspiron E1505 and it has done great. It runs alot faster than my old computer and now has windows XP service pack 3... recently I noticed that there was another network card in my device drivers and after hours of solving I figured out that it was a bluetooth driver. I have the icon LED on my computer keyboard and everytime I start it up, all the LEDs come on (eg:num lock, caps lock, scroll lock wifi and bluetooth), for post config or what ever. I found sofware to go with it online but it would not detect the hardware. Ive been through three software programs and none of them would detect the drivers. It is enabled in the device drivers, and it does have an assigned mac address and all. plus it came with the laptop so I figured it should work, but for some reason it doesent. I am almost completly out of ideas. any thing will help.

Thanks,
The guy with the old computers![image: Shows up in device manager] [image: Is enabled] [image: Software cant find it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It...U must enable it in the bios first before you do anything.